# mysql sum showing wrong answer for decimal type

Tags: mysql, decimal, sum

sales_id = 12 
product_rate = 2090.00
making_charge = 83.60    
handling_charge = 0.00

all of them are decimal(10,2) type. My query is

```
SELECT SUM( making_charge + product_rate + handling_charge ) AS tax_tourn
FROM  `sales_details` 
WHERE  `sales_id` =12
```

the result i am getting is 
 **tax_tourn = 10784.40**

which is not right

2090.00+83.60+0.00=**2173.60**

why is mysql showing wrong answer?

---

**Details Newly Added**

---

I have two tables sales and sales_details . sales_id is the primary key of sales and sales_details_id is the primary key for sales_details.
sales_id is the foreign key in  sales_details. 
There can multiple rows in sales_details with same sales_id.

But in our case (`sales_id` =12) there is only one row.

Comment: You don't need SUM aggregation function for a single row.

Comment: Check how many rows correspondng to `sales_id` =12, I suspect more than one row, if yes, then you need to bring one more cndition to make to work

Comment: I added new details to my question based on your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this code returns more than 1 as the answer you have more than 1 row matching your where clause.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM  `sales_details` 
WHERE  `sales_id` =12
```

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you have more than one row where `sales_id =12`.

Comment: +1 for realizing that. You should augment this answer to address the OP's use of the `SUM` aggregate function.

Comment: i checked and there is only one row for sales_id =12

Comment: Asaph, i dont understand what u said. i am very new to mysql. can u give me an example.

Comment: @praveenmon: then why did you accept another answer saying the same thing?